# Google Maps API: Trocar imagem padrão do marcador

Tags: android, imagem, google-maps-api-3

Olá, estou testando a API do Google Maps no meu aplicativo android, e fiquei sabendo que tem como trocar o icone do marcador padrão, porém, quando adicionei a minha imagem PNG ao projeto, o icone ficou com um tamanho absurdamente grande. Como posso fazer para não acontecer isso, contando que minha imagem possui uma resolção de 512x512?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa ter essa imagem em várias dimensões, dessa forma o próprio android se encarregará de subir a de melhor qualidade dependendo do aparelho.
Abaixo os tamanhos necessários de ícones:

MDPI - 48px

HDPI - 72px

XHDPI - 96px

XXHDPI - 144px

XXXHDPI - 192px

Depois setar a localização da imagem no `icon.`

```
private static final LatLng MELBOURNE = new LatLng(-37.813, 144.962);
  private Marker melbourne = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(MELBOURNE)
                            .title("Melbourne")
                            .snippet("Population: 4,137,400")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow)));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Agora vem aquele alívio de quem sofreu muito até aqui hahaha

Comment: haha que bom! Agora vai :)